# Getting multiple elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory :

```
 elements = $("input.newEntry:not([name^='counter'])");
    for (e in elements) {
        if (e.css('background-color') == 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)')
            alert("fire event");
    }
```

the error i get is e.css() is not a function. can i somehow cast e to a DOM object?

or is there any workaround for what i want to do?

Comment: Btw, DOM objects don't have a `css` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
elements = $("input.newEntry:not([name^='counter'])");

elements.each(function()
{
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)')
        alert("fire event");
});
```

On a side note, I don't think comparing to `background-color` like that is a good idea. Can't you use a class?

Comment: +1 for the class suggestion. CSS should not appear in your Javascript code. Use classes. Consider what happens if you change `0.6` to `0.7` in your CSS. You have to change your Javascript also... Use classes and the `hasClass()` jQuery method.

Comment: i have a big form, whose fields are being tested on change in many ways, turning the input bg color to green if it's valid. I think it's actually the simplest way to check the validity of the form before it's submitted.

Comment: @SpyrosMandekis You are shooting yourself in the foot. One small change, and you have to change a lot of things. At least add a class to the validated fields (jQuery: `.addClass('valid')`) and check for the existence of that. In your CSS, you can style the `valid` class to have a nice green background.

Comment: but you are actually right, i'll probably use .addClass to work it around

Answer (score 4):

`elements` is a jQuery collection (returned by the `$` function), so better treat it with the functions that jQuery itself provides to you. For example, if you want to iterate on a jQuery collection, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
elements = $("input.newEntry:not([name^='counter'])");
elements.each(function (i, e) {
    if ($(e).css('background-color') == 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)')
        alert("fire event");
    }
});
```

Also, in an `each()`, `this` will always refer to the current element, so you can even do this:

```
elements.each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') ...
});
```

Comment: `e` is not a jQuery object, but a DOM element. Use `$(e).css()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not iterate lists like that.

Use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var e = elements[i];
    ...
}
```

(or `$.each` as James suggests)

Your current for will not only yield all items in the array, but all members of the entire object, which will include jQuery functions such as `click`, `is`, etc., which do not have a `css` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
elements = $("input.newEntry:not([name^='counter'])");
elements.each(function (index, element) {
    var e = $(element);
    if (e.css('background-color') == 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)')
        alert("fire event");
});
```

`elements` is a jQuery object. If you loop through it, you also get the functions and properties of that object, not just the indices of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.newEntry:not([name^='counter'])").each(function() {
   if ($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)') {;
       alert("fire event");
   }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/